# get schema for Parquet file in StructType format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, pyarrow

I am trying to read a parquet file to save the schema, and then use this schema to assign it to dataframe while reading the csv file.

The file `fee.parquet` and `loan__fee.csv` has the same contents with different file formats.

Below is my code - I get an error that the schema should be 'StructType'. How do I convert the schema read from parquet file to StructType

```
from pyarrow.parquet import ParquetFile
import pyarrow.parquet
fee_schema = pyarrow.parquet.read_schema("/dbfs/FileStore/fee.parquet", memory_map=True)

df_mod = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/loan__fee.csv', header="true", schema=fee_schema)
```

It gives error :

> TypeError: schema should be StructType or string

I tried few options such as `fee_schema.to_string(show_schema_metadata = True)` but it does not work gives ParseError.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: why don't you use `spark.read.parquet` to read the parquet file, and get the schema from spark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by mck, you can use `spark.read.parquet` to get the schema - this command just fetch metadata from file, not reading it completely.  So you'll have something like this:

```py
src_df = spark.read.parquet("/FileStore/fee.parquet")
df_mod = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/loan__fee.csv', header="true", 
    schema=src_df.schema)
```